# Can't properly set PATH variable on linux for Java programs

Tags: java, linux, compiler-errors, path

I'm new at linux and java programming, I've been trying to run a test program but the only way for it to work is overwriting entirely the PATH.
This is the path I've set in the .bashrc:

`export PATH=:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.1/bin:`

and the JAVA_HOME:

`export JAVA_HOME=:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.1:`

When I run it like this, I get the following error: "`Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class FirstJavaProgram java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: FirstJavaProgram has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0`".

However, when I overwrite the path to just `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.1/bin`, it runs the program.

Do I have to set the PATH in a different way?

Comment: There probably is another java installation somewhere in the earlier elements of the path. Try to set your java folder as first entry.

Comment: `which java` can tell where the command is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment by [MDK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11948496/mdk) solved it:

> There probably is another java installation somewhere in the earlier elements of the path. Try to set your java folder as first entry. – MDK